# Return different types from different classes with the same approach

Tags: c++

I am not sure if I named the title right, but i will describe, what I am thinking about:

I am making a game and now I reached a point in which I want to refactor probably everything. The part which I want to refactor now is reading configuration and settings from file.

So far I used to store the information in a `std::map<MY_ENUM,std::string>` and then whenever I needed to read the value I returned from getter the string and parsed it in code(in a lot of places -> bad practice). By the way, the format of the config/settings file is simple: each line contains key and value.

Now, i thought about several upgrades to this:

1. Use template function which will return the type i need. Instead of parsing it everywhere I need the values, parse it in one place. The function would look something like `ResourceManager::Get<int>(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_LIMIT)`. There is risk of wrong interpretation of the variable though. Someone could parse one variable as string, while it should be parsed as float.
2. Friend proposed for the sake of simplicity to just make all the variables members of the class so they will be strongly typed and there would be no need to parse them, once they are stored.

Finally, the third approach is one I would like to ask about, if it is even possible in c++ (I believe it is, but I cannot figure it out), and how it can be done.

Let's say, we have two entries in the config file:

```
PLAYER_NAME  John Doe
CONNECTION_TIMEOUT 5
```

The way I imagine it would work is, i would have function, that would return some object representing the loaded entry, which would have function that would have specific type depending on the entry.

```
ResourceManager::get(PLAYER_NAME).getValue() // returns string
ResourceManager::get(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT).getValue() // returns int
```

I realize this won't work with simple inherited classes, since you cannot return different types from the same function.

Comment: The third option isn't possible with that syntax [edit: not completely true, c.f. François Andrieux's comment]. At best, you can have them return an union, a boost::variant, or something along those lines, or alternatively you could have `ResourceManager::getValue<PLAYER_NAME>()` (where PLAYER_NAME is a compile-time constant)

Comment: Don't use return values; pass a reference parameter instead.

Comment: @Caninonos It can work, if `PLAYER_NAME` and `CONNETION_TIMEOUT` are instances of type tags. Then template arguments could be deduced. Though you might as well use template arguments directly in that case, it's not impossible to make the third option work with that syntax.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux oh right. I assumed they had the same type, but that's not necessarily the case.

Comment: You are essentially dealing with a seralization/deserialization problem. My suggestion would be to use a well supported format (for example JSON) instaed of reinventing the wheel yourself and use one of the available C++ libraries to interface with it (for example RapidJSON).

Comment: @EmeraldWeapon yeah, that's another solution. nlohmann's JSON library is quite nice. I've used it few times.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Could you show me an example please?

Comment: I think @FrançoisAndrieux was referring to this: https://ideone.com/yInXJY (when he said it was feasible) and to something which looks a bit like this https://ideone.com/jHb7rp (when he said you might as well use template arguments directly, although I also removed the intermediate wrapper which is somewhat useless)